# How to pass props to screen in stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a top tab bar. Each tab has a stack navigator.

Dynamic navigator is here:

```
datas.forEach(function(data) {
    const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
        Home: HomePage
    }, {
        navigationOptions: {
            title: data.headerTitle
        }
    });
    tabs[data.headerTitle] = StackNavigator;
});

createMaterialTopTabNavigator(tabs, configs);
```

I want to pass data to HomePage. How can I do that? Below usage is not a valid syntax. I get below error:

> Reference Error: Can't find variable React

```
Home: { screen : props => <HomePage {...props} {...value} /> }
```

Answer (score 1):

Up in the top of your js file,

```
import React from 'react';
```

since you're using JSX in your js file, `React` is needed.